# Помогите в PHP со switch

Tags: php, switch

Делаю в скрипте подгрузку модулей в файле `index.php` с помощью `switch` и серверной директивы `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, но ничего не выходит.

Мне нужно, чтобы если пользователь ввёл адрес в браузере http://localhost/sign-in он попал на страницу авторизации.

Делаю вот так:

```
<?php

$action = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

switch($action) {

    case 'sign-in':
        require 'sign.php';
    break;

    default:
        echo 'Hello.';
}
```

При переходе по адресу http://localhost/sign-in выскакивает:

> ошибка 404, файл не найден.

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: перенесите эту логику на сторону апача, почитайте про htaccess и mod_rewrite

Comment: где вообще написан этот ваш пхп код,и почему он сам по себе должен вызываться?

Comment: А что нужно писать в htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, вам нужно перенаправить все запросы в один файл, например `index.php`

Для этого создайте в корне сайта файл `.htaccess` и поместите туда этот код

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

После этого можно обрабатывать запросы в указанном для перенаправления файле.

Что бы получить путь запроса - можно использовать эту строку `parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']`

Всё, теперь можно проверять, но адрес всегда начинается с `/`, это значит что нужно проверять не `sign-in`, а `/sign-in`.

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
switch($path) {
    case '/sign-in':
        echo 'Это адрес site/sign-in';
    break;

    default:
        echo 'Для этого адреса страница ещё не придумана';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, чтобы при переходе на http://localhost/sign-in не выскакивала ошибка 404, в папке 'sign-in' должен быть файл index.php с Вашим скриптом.

Во-вторых, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] возвращает имя скрипта. В переменной $action никак не может быть 'sign-in' - там '/sign-in/index.php'. Вот эту строку и пишите в case - тогда всё заработает.

Comment: Мне нужно создать что-то типа роутинга, допустим файл sign-in.php находится в папке modules.
Я через
<?php switch($action) {
case '/sign-in':
require 'modules/sign-in.php;
break;
}
?>
Указываю подгружаю его и при переходе на адрес http://localhost/sign-in должен загрузиться тот файл, который я подгрузил в switch. Надеюсь понятно обьяснил.

Comment: @ВадимРомашенко, а  switch-case Ваш - он в каком файле-то? Где он отрабатывает?

Comment: В файле index.php